# Cut a part of value in SQL Server using substring?

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have this data in my column:

```
32-HC-100-10001-G03P2-N-1-1001
```

The problem is my value doesn't have a fixed length. What I need to do is split this value into 2 columns `32-HC-100-10001-G03P2-N` and `1` - the numbers after last `-` don't important

Another example

```
4-G-100-10029-F23S-S-2-1001
```

should be split into `4-G-100-10029-F23S-S` and `2`. I have used `SUBSTRING([Line No#], 0, 21)` but because of the length it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way

```
declare @str varchar(100)=reverse('4-G-100-10029-F23S-S-2-1001')

select reverse(substring(@str,charindex('-',@str)+1,len(@str))) as first_col,
       left(substring(@str,charindex('-',@str)+1,len(@str)),charindex('-',substring(@str,charindex('-',@str)+1,len(@str)))-1) as second_col
```

May not be the shortest method but should get the job done

**Note :** I did not hard-code any *length* here

Answer (score 2):

As long as the last part(1-1001,2-2002...) have the same  number of values,this will work..

```
declare @string varchar(max)
set @string='32-HC-100-10001-G03P2-N-1-1001'

select replace(@string, right(@string,7),''),substring(right(@string,6),1,1)
```

**Output:**

```
32-HC-100-10001-G03P2-N         1
```

Answer (score 2):

When doing complex string operations in SQL Server, one method uses `outer apply` to simplify the calculations:

```
select t.col, s2.firstpart, s2.secondpart
from t outer apply
     (select left(col, len(col) - charindex('-', reverse(col)) as s1
      -- remove the last number
     ) s1 outer apply
     (select left(s1, len(s1) - charindex('-', reverse(s1)) as firstpart,
             right(s1, charindex('-', reverse(s1)) -1) as secondpart
     ) s2;
```

I find the calculations easier to construct, follow, and debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can try  this:

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max) = '32-HC-100-10001-G03P2-N-1-1001'

SELECT  REVERSE(STUFF(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string),CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@string))+1,LEN(@string)),1,CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string),CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@string))+1,LEN(@string))),'')),
        REVERSE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string),CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@string))+1,LEN(@string)),CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string),CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@string)),LEN(@string)))))
```

Output:

```
32-HC-100-10001-G03P2-N 1
```

If it is always comes as a 7th part you can use XML:

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max) = '32-HC-100-10001-G03P2-N-1-1001',
        @xml xml

SELECT @xml = CAST('<d>'+REPLACE(@string,'-','</d><d>') +'</d>' as xml)

SELECT  t.v.value('/d[1]','nvarchar(10)') + '-' +
        t.v.value('/d[2]','nvarchar(10)') + '-' +
        t.v.value('/d[3]','nvarchar(10)') + '-' +
        t.v.value('/d[4]','nvarchar(10)') + '-' +
        t.v.value('/d[5]','nvarchar(10)') + '-' +
        t.v.value('/d[6]','nvarchar(10)'),
        t.v.value('/d[7]','nvarchar(10)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/') as t(v)
```

Output:

```
32-HC-100-10001-G03P2-N 1
```

Comment: In your last `Charindex` function second parameter is **missing**

Comment: @Prdp Thanks, fixed it!